# Objective-C: Index Beyond Bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I am having a hard time figuring out what error i am really having with my code.
It says:

```
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

Here's the part where the app crashes.

```
NSString *keyTemp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Wit%d",indexPath.section+1];
    NSArray *arrTemp;
    if ([userStandards objectForKey:keyTemp] == nil || [[userStandards objectForKey:keyTemp] count]==3) {
        if ([witDict objectForKey:keyTemp] == nil) {
            arrTemp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",nil];
        } else {
            arrTemp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[witDict objectForKey:keyTemp]];
        }
        cell.inputTextArea.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@\nPhone: %@\nEmail: %@\nCity/State: %@\nZip: %@\nComments: %@",[arrTemp objectAtIndex:0],[arrTemp objectAtIndex:1],[arrTemp objectAtIndex:2], [arrTemp objectAtIndex:3], [arrTemp objectAtIndex:4], [arrTemp objectAtIndex:5]];
    } else {
        arrTemp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[userStandards objectForKey:keyTemp]];
        cell.inputTextArea.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@\nPhone: %@\nEmail: %@\nCity/State: %@\nZip: %@\nComments: %@",[arrTemp objectAtIndex:0],[arrTemp objectAtIndex:1],[arrTemp objectAtIndex:2], [arrTemp objectAtIndex:3], [arrTemp objectAtIndex:4], [arrTemp objectAtIndex:5]];
}
```

Comment: `count 3` != `element at index 3` - standart error

Answer (score 2):

Check your code :

```
if ([[userStandards objectForKey:keyTemp] count]==3)
{

  // Your array only have 3 elements (index 0,1, and 2)

  // Here you accessing index beyond 2
  cell.inputTextArea.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@\nPhone: %@\nEmail: %@\nCity/State: %@\nZip: %@\nComments: %@",[arrTemp objectAtIndex:0],[arrTemp objectAtIndex:1],[arrTemp objectAtIndex:2], [arrTemp objectAtIndex:3], [arrTemp objectAtIndex:4], [arrTemp objectAtIndex:5]];
}
```

Comment: I tried changing it to 6 and it still crashes with the same error.

Comment: @LakanBahande where you changed to 6?? Your array for key keyTemp only have 3 elements no?

Comment: It has 6, i tried changing also the count into 6 but have no effect.

Comment: @LakanBahande After changing count to 6 it won't comes under your if condition no? It will execute else..

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

Following line is correct 6 values are there in arrTemp.

```
arrTemp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",nil];
```

But in this only 3 are going in arrTemp.

```
arrTemp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[witDict objectForKey:keyTemp]];
```

You are entering in 2nd one....either add more key/values in keyTemp or change your logic.